# Multiple class bindings in AlpineJS?

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I'm trying to attach two `:class` bindings to a single element within an `x-for` loop. Usually this could be achieved by passing in a single object with multiple key:value pairs. In this instance however, one is a condition, the other is a property of the loop:

**Condition:**

`:class="{'active': colours.includes(arrayItem.class)}"`

**Property:**

`:class="arrayItem.class"`

Both of which work separately. I've tried adding them as separate attributes but only the first gets applied. I've also tried this (to no avail):

`:class="{'active': colours.includes(arrayItem.class), arrayItem.class}"`

I've searched through the docs but haven't found a solution.

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/owjbu1ay/10/

Answer (score 11):

You can use the array of classes when binding to the class attribute. The issue here is the object syntax `{}` here. You can use array of classes and use the ternary operator to conditionally render classes as shown below.

Now if the `colours` array includes the `arrayItem.class` it will apply the `active` class,

and the `arrayItem.class` will be the 2nd class applied without any conditions.

```html
:class="[colours.includes(arrayItem.class) ? 'active' : '' , arrayItem.class]"
```